# Multitouch pan scale rotate simultaneously in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need a way for a user to pinch, rotate and scale a  element using multitouch in javascript.

This is pretty easy with Objective C or Swift but seems to be a lot harder in javascript.

Can anyone give me a steer on what I should be using?

I'd like to do this code myself if possible - libraries like hammer.js don't work exactly as i would like (they tend to centre the div on the first finger which isn't nice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a multitude of **[touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)** available. On the Touch event object, you have an array of all touches, you can do what you want with those.

Comment: Do I just have to do all that math manually then? There's no helpful gesture stuff like in c / swift?